# Best Practice for Prefix to mark URL from backend as router navigatable internal URL

Tags: angular

I´m currently searching for a way to mark an URL fetched from the backend as an an angular 4 internal URL, which can be used with `router.navigate`.
 I want to add some kind of prefix to explicitly mark this URL as an possible route for my app to separate it from other links on the same host.

**Example:**
`[PREFIX]/myRoute/test` --> internal Route of my app
`/myRoute/externalResource` --> Link pointing to resource on the same host

The prefix should provide an unique way to separate app internal and other urls, since a test of the first slash without the prefix (`/myRoute`) would tell they are both identical.

**Is there something like a best practice** or similar to the `javascript:` prefix. I already took a look at the [official router documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links) but wasn´t succesfull